# Using alternative special functions in Simplify and Expand

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have Mathematica expressions involving the special functions `Erf[x]` and `Erfc[x]`, but I'd like to express them in terms of the scaled and translated version

```
F[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0,1]][x]
```

throughout the notebook. This is because `F[x]` has an easy interpretation in the context of my problem.

Comment: Please give an extended explanation of the behavior you desire, and at least a small sample of your code.

Comment: Link to the same question on MathGroup: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/5Bub8WAqd68/discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether I understand your problem, but I'm trying to answer my interpretation of what your saying.

So you have an expression in erf and erfc, like this

```
expr = Erf[x] + 1/Erfc[x] + Sin[Erf[x]] + Cos[Erfc[x]]
```

All it takes to replace erf and erfc with F is this:

```
 expr //. {Erfc[x_] -> 2 F[-(x) Sqrt[2]], Erf[x_] -> 1 - Erfc[x]}

 (* ==>  1 + Cos[2 F[-Sqrt[2] x]] + 1/(2 F[-Sqrt[2] x]) -
         2 F[-Sqrt[2] x] + Sin[1 - 2 F[-Sqrt[2] x]]
 *)
```

which with your definition of F[x] is indeed the same:

```
1 + Cos[2 F[-Sqrt[2] x]] + 1/(2 F[-Sqrt[2] x]) - 2 F[-Sqrt[2] x] + 
  Sin[1 - 2 F[-Sqrt[2] x]] /. F[x_] -> CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1]][x]

(* ==> 1 + Cos[Erfc[x]] + 1/Erfc[x] - Erfc[x] + Sin[1 - Erfc[x]] *)
```

Comment: This sounds like an application for UpSet (or TagSet).

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd. But it seems that with the replace rule, the functional definition of F[x] is lost. I'd like to keep the definition  `F[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1]][x]`  so that its derivatives etc behave as expected, and have the output appear in terms of F[x] rather than Erfc[x]. Possible?

Comment: @user1100309 I believe that is unfortunately not possible. Since you made a definition for F[x_] = ..., whenever Mathematica sees F[x], it will evaluate it. Here's a very similar alternative to Sjoerd's version: rewrite[expr_] := Simplify[ FunctionExpand@Simplify[expr] /. Erf[x_] :> 1 - 2 FI[Sqrt[2] x]] will rewrite and hopefully simplify expression in terms of FI.